# Why would I need `equals` if I have already `hashcode`?

Tags: java, hashing

I got a question about why we need equals if we have hashcode.

My first attempt was the answer because collision. But we corrected starting point with the assumption that we have not many objects so there is no collision at all.

My second attempt was the answer because of the speed. But I also got the reply that there is something conceptual difference between hashcode and equals.

So I read a lot of posts, the java doc and can not find the answer. Do I miss something?

Comment: Because Equals() can be implemented in ways other than comparing hash codes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089313

Comment: I write around 9 years in java. With the given assumptions and hint that the answer is not about performance. I can not find difference why not to use hashcode as equals, or wise verse. So there is some concept that I missing (or not)

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.  They're just not the same thing, that's all.  The default Equals() method compares *references,* not *hashcodes.*  Every other Equals() implementation is an override.  The Equals() method exists so that you can write any implementation of Equals() that you want, not just one that compares hashcodes.

Comment: To put it another way, *equivalency is not always defined by an object's hash.*  There might be some fields in my object that I don't want to participate in equivalency at all, and a hashcode is not going to work there (unless, of course, I exclude those fields from my hashcode computation).

Comment: In objects that already implement a comparator, all I have to do to implement Equals is to say `return objectA.Compare(objectB) == 0` or something similar.  Comparers don't use hashcodes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you! So answer is to simplify our developer life since it would be quite hard to write an math function that returns integer to satisfy equality

Comment: I'd say that it's because Equals() provides you with better flexibility.  Otherwise, we'd all just use hashcodes.  In any case, your teacher/interviewer/whoever clearly believes he knows conceptually the difference between hashcode and equals (though we might not necessarily agree with his reasoning).  Why don't you simply ask them?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops!  Retracted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the compareTo() has its own problems when you start getting situations where the numeric value is the same, but the internal state representations are different.  [Legitimate cases of having .equals() behaving inconsistently with .compareTo()?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/283030/40980) which I believe you should be familiar with.

Comment: There are already some good answers. I would add that Equals transfers a clear message about its meaning. And it is indeed to test for equality. A hash is a technical property that enables efficient access to collections, and it does not necessarily guarantee equality. Consider also that equality may be domain specific and does not necessarily mean identical. Equals compares objects so you may compare objects of different types. It could compare some kind of score, if the objects score the same they may be considered equal.

Comment: Because "the assumption that we have not many objects so there is no collision at all" is **wrong**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it bluntly: they serve different purposes.

- Equals is for testing equality.
- Hashcode is in order to produce an int (hopefully well distributed)

**if** your hashcode is *unique*, you could as well use it for equality. However, for many kind of objects, producing such a unique hash is plainly impossible.

Imagine an object containing two ints `a` and `b`. There is no way to produce a *unique* int hash for such an object. So you still need equality to compare them.

As for the comparator, it's usually a bad idea to use the output as hash because the result is not well distributed, resulting in lots of collisions when used in hash maps or similar data structures.

Comment: In addition to the risk of collision or the impossibility to produce a decent hash, there is also the fact that two objects having different hashes may be logically equals, because some objects properties may be not relevant to determine this equality. So even if same hashes (and no collision) should implies equality, different hashes does not implies inequality.

Comment: @mgoeminne "two objects having different hashes may be logically equals" is actually wrong. Citing the javadoc: "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result." ...which makes sense if you know how hashtables work

Comment: Wow, my mistake. I was actually (erroneously) remembering Chapter 3 of Effective Java. So a Rational class must implement hashCode in such a way that two Rational objects representing the same value but having different numerators and denominators (and therefore having potentially a different behavior) have the same hash. OR two Rational objects representing the same value with different numerators and denumerators must not be equal. Right?

Comment: Well, everything is alright as long as two equal objects have the same hash.

Answer (score 5):

For reasons of practicality, `hashCode()` returns a signed `int`. 2<sup>32</sup> possible values.  One could trivially have this be a `long` instead of an `int` and it would only slightly have me change the remainder of this answer.

The essence of all of this is the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  If you have `m` items and try to put them in `n` boxes and `m > n`, then you will have two items that go in the same box.

Lets look at the [hashCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.hashCode%28%29) for `Long` - which can have 2<sup>64</sup> values.  Since 2<sup>64</sup> > 2<sup>32</sup> you will have two values that has to the same value.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
}
```

So, lets write some quick code.

```
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(0).hashCode());
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(-1).hashCode());
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(0).equals(Long.valueOf(-1)));
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(0).hashCode() == Long.valueOf(-1).hashCode());
```

This prints out:

```
0
0
false
true
```

And there we have it.  Two numbers.  One of them is `0` and the other is `-1` that have the same hash code, but not the same number.

<sup>The hex value of `-1` is `0xffffffffffffffff` which when you do an `0xffffffff ^ 0xffffffff` you get `0`</sup>

**But wait! What if we used `long` for the hashCode instead!**

As I said, its only a slightly different problem. I would have to start digging into another class that has the possibility of having more values than hashCodes, like [BigInteger](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.hashCode%28%29) or [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29) or [Inet6Address](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Inet6Address.java#Inet6Address.hashCode%28%29) (2<sup>128</sup> possible values).  All it does is make the calculation of the hashCode a bit harder to do right here (those are more than a line long with two bit operations). It doesn't change that the hashCode, being a fixed size value, is subject to the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: As an aside, an implementation of hash code for a numeric object that has a collision between 0 & -1 is frankly appalling. What were they thinking?

Comment: @Jules well, there are 2^32 longs that collide with a hash code of 0. Consider a 8 bit hash code (so I don't have to type lots).  How do you hash `0xFFFF` so that it makes use of all the bits to *try* to get the best distribution. Remember, you've got to hash it into a space of `0x??`.  I believe unless you really start doing esoteric things on it that make the hash far less optional for speed, you *will* get -1 hashing to some other common value.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a 64 bit hash code. There are 2^64 possible hash codes. Now lets say you are hashing strings. There are many, many more than 2^64 strings. There are 2^64 strings of eight 8-bit characters alone. There are 256 times more strings of nine 8-bit characters and even more strings of 10, 11 or more charcters. Obviously there will be many, many 9 character and even more longer strings with the same hash code.

Therefore you can't rely on the hash code alone. Equal hash codes don't guarantee that the objects are identical.

Comment: Given that this is discussing Java, the hashCode is a 32 bit signed value.  [Long.hashCode()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.hashCode%28%29) is enough to cause a problem and it can be trivially shown how two different longs can have the same hashCode().